# Embed chromium with extension support

Tags: google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-extension, chromium, chromium-embedded

I'd like to experiment with building a browser based on Chromium, ideally with support for Chrome-extensions.

I've looked into the [Chromium Embedded Framework](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef), which does not include support for extensions.

Are the only options available to either:

- reimplement the extension-API on top of CEF; or to
- base the project on the Chromium source,

or are there other alternatives?

Comment: For what it's worth, CEF [plans to implement](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/issues/1947/add-support-for-chrome-extensions) extensions support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are the only options available to either:
>
> - reimplement the extension-API on top of CEF; or
> - to base the project on the Chromium source,

Pretty much. But, as wOxxOm mentions in comments, [CEF plans to implement the API](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/issues/1947/add-support-for-chrome-extensions) - *eventually*.